# Unit testing with Jest vs MQTT

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, mqtt

I'm writing the test cases for API, using Jest and MQTT. I want to validate the response value of the message with my expected value. Currently, I cannot handle the response of function client.on. Please help me to resolve it, thanks so much

***test.ts***

```
    async doTest() {

        client.on('connect', async function () {
            await client.subscribe(topic + '/reply', function (err) {
                 if (!err) {
                   client.publish(topic, JSON.stringify(payload));
                 }
            });
        });

        await client.on('message', async function (topic, message) {
              // message is Buffer
              const res = await JSON.parse(message.toString());
              const { err, response } = res;
              this.result = JSON.stringify(response);
        });
}

    async getResult() {
         return this.result;
}
```

test.spec.ts

```
it('should call api', async () => {
    await test.doTest();
    result = await test.getResult();
    console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by "cannot handle"? What have you tried, what result did you expect, and what happened instead?

Comment: hi @PaulBissex, I want to compare the response of the message with my expected value. I've try to get the response in the client.on, when the message returns a value, I put it into the result variable. But currently, when I do the test case, the value of the result always is undefined. My expected is: when I subscribe and publish the topic, it will be reply for me the response that is matched with my expected.

Comment: How are you mocking the MQTT client?